# find folders in a tree and create a list with their paths

Tags: python

I have big folder tree and I need to make a list with the path of every folder named "arc".
The folder tree is something like:

```
./tree
--> ./A
----> ./one
------> ./arc
--> ./B
--> ./C
----> ./two
------> ./arc
--> ./D
--> ./E
----> ./three
--> ./F
----> ./four
------> ./arc
```

My final list should be [/tree/A/one/arc, /tree/C/two/arc, /tree/F/four/arc]
(note that arc is always in the fourth level of the tree)

I've been trying with the os.walk function but haven't been successful. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Once you know how to list subdirectories, there's is only some very basic programming left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_list = [os.path.join(root,dir) for
    root,dirs,files in os.walk("path/to/tree") for
    dir in dirs if dir=="arc"]
```

`os.walk(path)` returns a list of tuples, containing:

```
(the root directory for this recursion,
 a listing of all subdirectories in that root,
 a listing of all the files in that root)
```

So we're going through `os.walk` and looking at all the `dirs` tuples, pulling each one and checking to see if it's `"arc"`. If it is, it's combining the `root` (which is something like `'path/to/tree/A/One'` with the dir name (which should always be `'arc'`) using `os.path.join` (which puts the OS-specific path separator between each argument), and adding that to the list comp.

Comment: @Guillermo.D I'm glad it worked! Doubly so since I never tested it.....:) If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as "Accepted" using the check mark under the voting arrows.